# "On en fait quelque chose d'amusant" -- what exactly does "en" refer to in this passage?

Tags: grammaire

> — Est-ce que pour toi la grammaire est synonyme de plaisir, Rylan?
>
> — D'habitude non, mais on **en** fait quelque chose d'amusant, tu ne trouves pas ? Donc !, qu'est-ce qui sera au programme de la seconde partie de notre spectacle?

Once again, I'm not sure how to understand the way the pronoun **en** is used here. Without it, the sentence says basically this: **usually not, but we're doing something fun, don't you think?** But how does **en** alter its meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*En* refers to ***la grammaire***:

> *On fait **de la grammaire** quelque chose d'amusant.*

Note also that *faire quelque chose* translates to "to make something" instead of "to do something" in this sentence:

> Grammar is usually boring but we are making something fun **of it**.